# How to concat a string from a class in xamarin forms?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a label inside my listview

```
<Label Text="{Binding Price,StringFormat='GlobalVariable.Currency{0:F0}'}"
```

Result should be : $0.00

I want to concat the currency to the price

My Global Variable Class:

```
public Static Class GlobalVariable
{
  Currency="$";
}
```

// currency can be changable.

**so how to concat the currency from a class to xaml?**

Answer (score 2):

It is not possible out of the box. See this [topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5593635/xaml-stringformat-and-static-strings) for more info: 
If I were you, I would either:

1. format string on ViewModel layer,
2. use ValueConverter for converting the value.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a converter:

```
public class CurrencyConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        string value = value as string;
        return GlobalVariable + value;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
       throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

In your Page.xaml

```
 <ContentPage.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <converter:CurrencyConverter x:Key="currencyConverter" />
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </ContentPage.Resources>
```

then, the binding

```
<Label Text="{Binding Price,Converte={StaticResource currencyConverter}}" />
```